# Redux Toolkit, useSelector returns the previous state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to react and react redux and im facing that problem where I can't get to the latest state provided by useSelector.

I'm trying to make a filter that allows users to filter products by categories using multiple checkboxes. (f.e. checking backpacks and jackets will show items with these characters included in the title)

I want to mention that when I used useRef hook for sorting function everything works fine and useSelector returns the current value.

This is the shop navigation where user can sort and filter items.

```
const ShopNavigation = () => {
    const filterValue = useSelector(state => state.filteringClothes.filterValue)
    const [filterCategory, setFilterCategory] = useState([])
    const typeRef = useRef('none')
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const sortHandler = () => {
        if (typeRef.current.value === 'none') {
            dispatch(sortingActions.sortNone())
        }
        if (typeRef.current.value === 'priceAsc') {
            dispatch(sortingActions.sortPriceAsc())
        }
        if (typeRef.current.value === 'priceDes') {
            dispatch(sortingActions.sortPriceDes())
        }
        if (typeRef.current.value === 'titleAsc') {
            dispatch(sortingActions.sortA_Z())
        }
        if (typeRef.current.value === 'titleDes') {
            dispatch(sortingActions.sortZ_A())
        }
    }
    const filterHandler = e => {
        if (e.target.checked === true) {
            setFilterCategory(filterCategory => [...filterCategory, e.target.value])
            dispatch(filteringActions.newFilterValue(filterCategory))
        } else {
            setFilterCategory(filterCategory.filter(item => item !== e.target.value))
            dispatch(filteringActions.newFilterValue(filterCategory))
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className='shop-navigation'>
            <div className='shop-navigation__wrapper'>
                <div className='shop-navigation__sort'>
                    <label htmlFor='sort'>Sort</label>
                    <select onChange={sortHandler} name='sort' id='sorting' defaultValue='none' ref={typeRef}>
                        <option value='none'>None</option>
                        <option value='priceAsc'>Lowest Price</option>
                        <option value='priceDes'>Highest Price</option>
                        <option value='titleAsc'>A-Z</option>
                        <option value='titleDes'>Z-A</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div className='shop-navigation__category'>
                    <p>Categories</p>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='backpacks' value='backpack' onClick={filterHandler} />
                    <label htmlFor='backpacks'>Backpacks</label>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='jackets' value='jacket' onClick={filterHandler} />
                    <label htmlFor='jackets'>Jackets</label>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='t-shirts' value='shirt' onClick={filterHandler} />
                    <label htmlFor='t-shirts'>T-Shirts</label>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='sleeves' value='sleeve' onClick={filterHandler} />
                    <label htmlFor='sleeves'>Sleeves</label>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='casual' value='casual' onClick={filterHandler} />
                    <label htmlFor='casual'>Casual</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

By pressing checkboxes, filterHandler is activated and dispatches an action of sending these values of strings to the filterValue state (array) in filtering slice.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
const filteringSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'filtering',
    initialState: { filterValue: [] },
    reducers: {
        newFilterValue(state, action) {
            state.filterValue = action.payload
        },
    },
})

export const filteringActions = filteringSlice.actions
export default filteringSlice
```

In ProductList component. I need the latest data for the filterHandler (im currently working on it) from filtering-slice state to filter array of objects and show only these items that contain the characters which are stored in filterValue array.

Example: If filterValue's state is ['jacket', 'backpack'] I want to show objects that in their key title jacket or backpack word is included.

Comment: I am facing the same issue did you find any solution? Thank you

Comment: I decided to keep the state inside useRef

Comment: well I found that useSelector in typescript returns data on next request or on another component means I have a component name Products which has a child component name ProductItem then when I pass products array which I got from useSelector to the child component then I can see list of products in child component but parent component returns empty array and then on next request it returns me previous state.